# Should I use "to" or "until" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm writing a formal report. Which one of the following sentences is better.

> There are some problems which take too much time **to** get their solutions.
>
> There are some problems which take too much time **until** get their solutions.

I have the the following sense about using "to" in a sentence. Please tell me, is it correct?

"To" is used to demonstrate, subject of the sentence is going to do a rather difficult / big / noticeable work. For example, consider the following sentences.

> Please try to call me. (Here, process of calling seems to be too hard)
>
> Please try call me. (here, it seems to be an ordinary work)

If this statement is correct, does it apply to the first real sentence? (*"There some problems ..."*)

Comment: In your second question (which should be asked separately) "Please try to call me" means *make an attempt to call me* (with no implication that this is part of any greater "objective, desired result"). *Please try call me* is not a valid English construction. *Please try calling me* would almost always be understood to mean there's a greater (but unstated) goal, which *might* be achieved or furthered by calling me.

Comment: In the first question, *get their solutions* isn't very natural phrasing. Apart from anything else, the problems themselves don't actually *get* or *do* anything. Normal phrasing would be *take too much time to **solve*** (or even more succinctly, *take **too long to solve***).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two different questions:

1) "until" can only introduce a clause (that means, a subject and verb must come after "until.") So "until get their solutions" is never right; "to" is correct.

2) "Please try to call me"/"please try call me"; unfortunately, the pattern you have guessed is not correct. In fact, the second sentence would never be said; it's impossible to put a bare verb after "try;" the infinitive is necessary. (Perhaps you have heard "please try and call me" which is an informal way to say "try to call me.")

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW, I've seen ["Please try call me"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=%22Please+try+call+me%22) in many texts.

Comment: Is it informally correct? for example, daily speakings

Comment: @abforce. no, no native English speaker would ever say "please try call me" in any context, no matter how informal; it just isn't English. I also don't see the Google hits you are seeing.

Comment: @abforce - Also, don't assume that something is correct just because you saw it on the internet.  There are many people on the internet who do not speak English as their first language.